# Distribute By vs Shuffle in SparkSQL Query Join

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I believe that in Spark when there is a `JOIN` between two tables, both the tables are distributed to the partitions on the same join-key to **co-locate** the data (from both the tables) to find a match. If I am not mistaken, this action is called `SHUFFLE`.

However, I also read that there is a `DISTRIBUTE BY` clause which can be used in a sql query to also pre-distribute the data by the specified key. So logically using a `distribute by` on the joining tables before a Join will also give the same results as a normal SHUFFLE.

For. e.g:

```
create or replace temporary view cust AS
select id, name
from customers
distribute by id;

create or replace temporary view prods AS
select id, pname
from products
distribute by id;

select a.id, a.name, b.pname
from cust a
INNER JOIN prods b
ON a.id = b.id
```

So, if `distribute by` also distributes the data to co-locate the data in both the tables, how is it any different from a `Shuffle` ? Can a `distribute-by` eliminate `shuffle` ?
Also, how can a `distribute by`/`cluster by` be leveraged to elevate query performance.

If possible, please share an example.

Can anyone please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the manuals:

> DISTRIBUTE BY
>
> Repartition rows in the relation based on a set of expressions. Rows with the same expression values will be hashed to the same
>   worker. You cannot use this with ORDER BY or CLUSTER BY.

It amounts to the same thing. I.e. shuffle occurs, that is to say you cannot eliminate it, just alternative interfaces. Of course, only possible due to 'lazy' evaluation employed.

Comment: so if `DISTRIBUTE BY + SORT BY` is synonymous to shuffles or causes shuffles, then how does it help in query performance ? So, what is the use of `DISTRIBUTE BY` or `CLUSTER BY` before joining tables since Spark will anyway shuffle the data as per the join keys to co-locate the data. In what scenarios the same should be leveraged ?

Comment: your question was is it the same thing? i answered that. its just an alterbative to repartition, using %sql approach.